# Javascript / JQuery Array of objects intersection by property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Given two arrays:

```
var users = [{ name: 'Alice', typeID: 1 }, { name: 'Bob', typeID: 2 }, { name: 'Carol', typeID: 3 }];
var authorized = [{ typeID: 1 }, { typeID: 2 }];
```

I would like to know the simplest way to get all users having typeId that is present in the authorized array.

In this case the result should be:

```
[{ name: 'Alice', typeID: 1 }, { name: 'Bob', typeID: 2 }]
```

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = users.filter(function(user) {
  return authorized.some(function(authorizedObj) {
    return authorizedObj.typeID === user.typeID;
  });
})
```

Should be noted that if your authorized array contained just the ID's and not objects (something like `[1, 2]`), then the solution would be simpler:

```
var result = users.filter(function(user) {
  return authorized.indexOf(user.typeID) !== -1;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a short solution with linear complexity, **O(n+m)**, and with the help of a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var users = [{ name: 'Alice', typeID: 1 }, { name: 'Bob', typeID: 2 }, { name: 'Carol', typeID: 3 }],
    authorized = [{ typeID: 1 }, { typeID: 2 }],
    map = new Map,
    result;

authorized.forEach(a => map.set(a.typeID, true));
result = users.filter(a => map.has(a.typeID));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: O(m + n) ~ O(2n) ~ O(n)

Comment: @mortezaT, what means `~` in this case?

Comment: They're similar and can be replaced; O(n) and O(2n) considered as O(n).

Comment: i know. any linear content stays linear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var types = authorized.reduce(function(types, type) { types.push(type.typeID); return types; }, []);

var usersMatched = users.filter(function(user) { return types.indexOf(user.typeID) !== -1;});
```

maybe there is a more efficient solution, but it is something to start with